# Minimizing a product of factorials

Tags: calculus, factorial

Im trying to minimize $n_1! n_2! \cdots n_k!$ under the constraint $n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_k = N$ and $n_i > 0$ for all $i$. I know the answer is that it is minimized if all $n_i$ are equal to $\frac{N}{k}$ for all $i$. There is already [a post on this forum about maximizing](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565496/495499) and apparently [one answer there is given for minimizing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/565554/495499). But i’m having a very hard time understanding it since this is my first time seeing gamma and betta functions. I tried to use induction but i got stuck there too. I’m a first year math major.

Comment: The gist of the proof is that $(n+k)!(n-k)!>n! ^2$ so basically if any two pairs $n_i, n_j$ are unequal you'll get a lower value if you make them equal so they must all be equal. The upper inequality is generally easy to proof for integers, for non-integers i.e gamma function it probably shouldn't be hard to proof but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n_1, \ldots, n_k$ satisfies the constraint and $n_{\max} - n_{\min} > 1$. Then increasing the smallest $n_i$ by one and decreasing the largest $n_i$ by one leads to another configuration that satisfies the constraint.
Furthermore this changes the product of factorials by a factor of
$\frac{(n_{\min}+1)! (n_{\max}-1)!}{n_{\min}! n_{\max}!}
= \frac{n_{\min}+1}{n_{\max}} < 1$. Therefore, the original configuration was not the minimizing choice.

Thus, the minimizing choice must satisfy either $n_{\max}-n_{\min}=1$ or $n_{\max}-n_{\min}=0$. If $N$ is divisible by $k$, then the latter is possible; otherwise the best one can do is the the former case with a configuration consisting of $n_i$ being a combination of $\lfloor N/k\rfloor$ and $\lceil N/k \rceil$.